# Skype : is there a way to autofocus the field text when you navigate between conversations?

Tags: skype

It's actually pretty anoying. You know, you get a message from your coworker, you click on his name to see the message, and, like a idiot, you start typing in order to answer him, and .. NO. Skype "autofocus" the search field.

That's in my opinion an incredible mistake : you add / search contact really less often than answering to conversation ... And i'm sure i'm not the ony one to complain about this behaviour : its definitly a waste of time to select the text message field, then typing.

Any idea ?

Comment: What version of Skype are you using? In version 6.19 (452), any conversations initiated or replied to begin with focus in the message field.

Comment: 6.18. I have all my coworkers to this version (and we dont want to get the ugly new version ;))

Comment: Darn. 6.18 flat, or a specific revision?

Comment: 6.18.0.106 on my computer, but the problem I have explained is real for many years ;)
One friend told me that with the unix Version of Skype, the focus on the message box is good :)

Comment: In the "new" Skype version built-in Windows 10, this ** behavior comeback!